# Next-Auth: after clicking login redirect to verify doesnt working

Tags: javascript, next.js, next-auth

i'm implemented email provider authorization with custom signIn form in my next.js app.
after clicking login it must redirect to verifyRequest form, but it doesnt. funny moment is that email that confirms login sends and works correctly.

*signIn.ejs:*

```
  <form method="POST" action="/api/auth/signin/email">
    <input type="hidden" name="remember" defaultValue="true" />
    <div className="rounded-md shadow-sm -space-y-px">
      <div>
        <label htmlFor="email" className="sr-only">
          Email
        </label>
        <input
          id="email"
          onChange={(e)=>{setEmail(e.target.value)}}
          name="email"
          type="email"
          autoComplete="email"
          required
          placeholder="Email"
        />
      </div>
    </div>

    <div>
      <button
        type="submit"
        onClick={() => signIn("email", { email, callbackUrl } )}
      >
        <span>
          <HiLockClosed />
        </span>
        Login
      </button>
    </div>
  </form>
```

---

```
export async function getServerSideProps(context) {
  try {
    const { req } = context;
    const session = await getSession({ req });
    if (session) {
      return {
        redirect: {
          destination: '/dashboard',
          permanent: false,
        },
      };
    }
  } catch (e) {
    console.error(e);
  }

  return {
    props: { callbackUrl: `${url.client}/dashboard` },
  };
}
```